# Unit test a page with an ion-list containing a [virtualScroll] attribute

Tags: ionic-framework, jasmine, ionic3, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm wondering how to make sure that an `ion-list` displays the correct content.

The `ion-list` looks like this:

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="list" [approxItemHeight]="'132px'">
  <ion-item *virtualItem="let item">
    <span item-start>{{item.foo}}</span>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The unit test:

```
it('should display the correct content', () => {
  comp.list = [ { foo: 'bar' } ];
  fixture.detectChanges();

  de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('ion-content'));
  el = de.nativeElement;

  console.log(el);
});
```

This outputs:

```
<ion-list class="list list-md virtual-loading" ng-reflect-virtual-scroll="[object Object],[object Object" ng-reflect-approx-item-height="132px">
    <!---->
</ion-list>
```

How to trigger karma to render an `ion-item` in the `ion-list`?

Answer (score 0):

You have manually emit the update event in the test:

```
const virtualScrollComponent = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(VirtualScrollComponent)).componentInstance;
virtualScrollComponent.update.emit(list);
```